# Why I am getting a different sum if invoked with different number of threads in parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is just an extension of the following question I asked:

[Why can't I reach 100% CPU utilization with my parallel tasks code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62099331/why-cant-i-reach-100-cpu-utilization-with-my-parallel-tasks-code)

```
 private static int SumParallel()
        {
            var intList = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000_000_000);
            int count = intList.Count();
            int threads = 6;
            List<Task<int>> l = new List<Task<int>>(threads);
            for(int i = 1; i <= threads; i++)
            {
                int skip = ((i - 1) * count) / threads;
                int take = count / threads;
                l.Add(GetSum(intList, skip, take));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(l.ToArray());
            return l.Sum(t => t.Result);
        }

private static Task<int> GetSum(IEnumerable<int> list, int skip, int take)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 int temp = 0;
                 foreach(int n in list.Skip(skip).Take(take))
                 {
                     if (n % 2 == 0)
                         temp -= n;
                     else
                     {
                         temp += n;
                     }
                 }

                 Console.WriteLine(temp + " " + Task.CurrentId);
                 return temp;
             });
        }
```

If I modify the number of tasks working in parallel, I get a different sum.

Why is this so?

Comment: `WaitAll` is blocking call

Comment: This is needed, I have to wait for all of them to finish, only then I have the result.

Comment: How many cores does you micro have?  You are creating processes and depending on how the operating system is swapping processes will determine the CPU utilization.

Comment: it can be simplified to `return ParallelEnumerable.Range(1, 1000_000_000).Sum(n => n % 2 == 0 ? -n : n)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq

Comment: You are dealing with large numbers, and so there is the possibility of arithmetic overflow. I suggest that you enclose the calculations in [`checked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) blocks, to rule out this possibility: `checked { temp -= n; }`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias This is why I didn't just calculate plain sum of all range of integers, rather I made every other integer negative which ruled out this exception. Otherwise, I was always getting arithmetic overflow exception, even if I applied `checked` operator. Actually, because of unable to solve that problem, I changed my code to make every alternate number negative.

Comment: @teenup hmm, the compiler option "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow" is not seem to be enabled by default, so normally you shouldn't get exceptions unless you use the `checked` keyword. Anyway, if this was a real production application, you should probably use a `long` accumulator instead of `int`, to make the possibility of overflow very tiny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
int skip = ((i - 1) * count) / threads;
int take = count / threads;
```

consider `threads = 3` and `count = 10`
It can't cover all of your list. Based on thread count you get different roundings in `take` and `skip` and sometimes they can't cover all items in the list.

You maybe should change it this way:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= threads; i++)
{
    int skip = ((i - 1) * count) / threads;
    int take = count / threads;

    if(i == threads)
        take = threads - skip;

    l.Add(GetSum(intList, skip, take));
}
```

Comment: You have guessed the problem correctly. I solved it using this `int skip = (i - 1) * take;`, with another change for `take` if it is a final iteration. Thanks.